# Will the empty value get nullified in text area?

Tags: customsetting

I have entered empty value in one of the fields in custom settings (by jus pressing space in the text area field). But when I check in my page , it is showing "null" instead of showing empty value (" "). My question is even though if we give empty values , it will get nullified ?  Or this only happens in text area ?

I want to get the value as empty instead of null. please provide me a solution.. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't store a "blank" value in any type of field. All text fields require at least one non-blank character to avoid being null. Also, leading and trailing whitespace is automatically stripped by the database.